# event.pageX and event.pageY undefined in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the onclick listener inside an a tag

```
onclick="showMap('change-img-box',event); return false;"
```

This is the jquery

```
function showMap(id,e){
var hpos = e.pageX, ypos = e.pageY; alert(hpos+'----'+ypos);
if($("#"+id).is(":visible")){
    $("#"+id).hide();
}else{
    $("#"+id).css({"top": ypos+10, "left": hpos+10}).hide().fadeIn(300);
}
}
```

Not sure why, but IE 7 says that both hpos and ypos are undefined. How can I fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `clientX` and `clientY` in IE 8 and below. [More info](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position)

Comment: If you use jQuery to bind the event handler rather than using an onclick attribute, the pageX and pageY should be normalized across browsers automatically, though i haven't tested that recently.

Comment: Very helpful: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jquery already, you can initialize the click event using jquery instead of the inline onclick. jQuery normalizes the event object according to W3C standards (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
$('#thing-you-are-clicking').click( function(e) {
    var hpos = e.pageX, ypos = e.pageY;
    // Do your stuff here...
});
```

if you need that 'id' data, you can put it into the dom of your button using a data-* property, e.g.

```
<a href="#" id="thing-you-are-clicking" data-id="change-img-box">Hi</a>
```

then you can access the data using .data('id')

```
$('#thing-you-are-clicking').click( function(e) {
    var hpos = e.pageX, ypos = e.pageY;
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // Do your stuff here...
});
```

Comment: This was not exactly what I needed, but it definilty gave me the idea to solve my issue. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of IE use `clientX` and `clientY` instead. Here's the function I use for cross-browser compatibility:

```
window.getMouseCoords = function(e) {
    if( !e) return {x:0,y:0};
    if( e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        return {x:e.pageX,y:e.pageY};
    }
    if( e.clientX || e.clientY) {
        return {
            x:e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
            y:e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop
        };
    }
    return {x:0,y:0};
};
```